# Android studio 3.6 give an redline for android:screenOrientation="portrait", need to change android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-studio-3.6

When I update the android studio 3.6 its give me a red line below `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.

And its say's to change to `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"`

Can anyone have any idea what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 2):

In Android studio 3.6.0 i guess they want the user to handle the orientation and encourage developer to use ViewModel stuff. Let me explain screenOrientation in detail

`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

will give you error you have to either specify

`android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" or android:screenOrientation="unspecified"`

**fullSensor** Means either you have ON the "Rotate off" or not it will change the orientation based on you move the phone

**unspecified** Means if you have ON the Rotate off then it will stay only in that orientation and if not then it will change the orientation based on you move the phone.

Comment: so as per your answer we got only two choices, so what if i want to lock the orientation to portrait only ?

Comment: What if I want orientation "portrait" mode only.

Comment: In application tag apply tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity", Which ignore all your warnings for screenOrientation.

Answer (score 2):

To build on Deep Sheth's answer, this is a warning not an error.

As it suggests you set the `fullSensor` or `unspecified` in your activity so that *the user can use the application in any orientation and provide a great experience in Chrome OS devices*.

You can make that warning go away by adding the following to your activity declaration in the manifest: `tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"`

Answer (score 0):

I have used bellow  ..

1. Add manifest file bellow lines ..

   ```
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
   ```
2. manifest file will look like..

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.yourpackage"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
   .....
   <activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

    </manifest>
   ```